# Laravel 5 Auth::attempt by a custom controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

Am getting the below error, when I try to implement Auth::attempt()

The controller I have looks like

```
 Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Models\User given
```

The controller I have looks like

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;



class AdminAjaxController extends Controller {
    public function getLogin()
    {
        $data = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' =>Input::get('password'));
        Auth::attempt($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably upgraded to a new version?

Comment: @Luceos no I did not do any upgrade, a fresh installation of L5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error gone by changing the driver in Auth.php from Eloquent to Database